# Uso de auto referencia

Tags: java

Sobre o uso da auto referencia `this`queria saber qual a diferença de se fazer:

```
public static class Aluno{
    private String nome;

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }
    public Aluno(){
        this.nome="abc";
    }
}
```

e de se fazer:

```
public static class Aluno{
    private String nome;

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }
    public Aluno(){
        nome="abc";
    }
}
```

qual a diferença entre `this.nome` e `nome`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O uso do this é usado em 3 situações:

1. A mais comum é utilizada em propriedades para distinguir a variáveis do método com os atributos das classes, ex:

   ```
           public class Pessoa{

           private String nome;

           public void setNome(String nome) {
               //para diferenciar o parametro da variavel utilizamos o this para dizer que é da classe essa variavel.
               this.nome = nome;
           }

           // ...
       }
   ```

2.O segundo quando existe a necessidade de passar uma instancia da classe atual para outra classe através de parâmetros.

```
    public class Carro
    {
    private String nome;

    private Modelo modelo = new Modelo();



    public String Modelo()
    {
        return modelo.CarroModelo(this);
    }

    // ...
    public String getModelo()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }
 }



  public class Modelo
  {

    public String CarroModelo(Carro carro)
    {
        //Instancia do Objeto Carro
        String Nome = carro.getModelo();
        return Nome;
        // ...
    }
}
```

3. Chamar construtores alternativos em uma classe.

   ```
    class Pessoa
    {

   //Ao instanciar este objeto alem do construtor padrao Pessoa ele irá chamar também o construtor com parametro.
   public Pessoa(){
       this("Construtor com parametro");


   }

   public Pessoa(String nome)
   {

   }


   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

No exemplo apresentado não há nenhuma, ambos se referem ao campo `nome`.

No entanto, há situações em que isso não acontece.
Veja o caso deste exemplo:

```
public void setNome(String nome){
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

Aqui é necessário fazer a distinção entre o campo e o parâmetro do método.

Comment: Agora entendi; Agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de que o `this` neste seu exemplo está referindo ao mesmo atributo, não fazendo diferença alguma, em uma instância ou um construtor o `this` é uma palavra reservada que referencia o objeto atual - o objeto cujo método ou construtor está sendo chamado. Você pode se referir a qualquer membro do objeto atual de dentro de um método de instância ou um construtor usando isso.

> `this`: refere-se a instância atual do objeto

Como por exemplo em Java podemos ter um parâmetro de
um método e um atributo de uma classe
com o mesmo nome. Caso façamos uma
referência a esta variável, pelo princípio
da localidade estaremos referenciando
aquela variável cuja declaração estiver
mais próxima, no caso o parâmetro. Caso
desejemos referenciar o atributo da classe
e não o parâmetro devemos usar a
palavra reservada `this` antes do nome da
variável.

Além do seu exemplo, veja um outro exemplo, mais visível, na prática como seria:

Sem o `this`:

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
```

Com o `this`:

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    //constructor
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Veja mais detalhes [**na documentação**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

#### Outras palavras reservadas

Veja a lista de palavras reservadas definidas até a versão 7 da linguagem:

> package | import | new | class | interface | enum | abstract | final |
>   implements | extends | instanceof | public | private | protected |
>   super | this throw | throws | try | catch | finally | if | else | for
>   | do  while   switch  case | default | break | continue | return boolean |
>   byte | short | int | long double | float | char | void | strictfp |
>   transient volatile | synchronized | native | assert | static goto |
>   const | true | false | null

Referências

- [Palavras reservadas do Java](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/83/as-52-palavras-reservadas-do-java.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No seu exemplo não tem diferença, estão se referindo ao mesmo atributo.

```
public static class Aluno{
    private String nome;

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    Aluno(){
        this.nome="abc";
    }
}
```

Agora se o exemplo for outro, o `this` vai fazer referência ao atributo da classe.

```
public static class Aluno{
    private String nome;

    public String setNome(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

No caso do método `setNome(String nome);` o `this.nome` faz referencia ao atributo da classe `Aluno` e o `nome` **sem** o `this` faz referencia o atributo recebido por parâmetro no método.